Copying a chapter from thesis and pasting it a separate file change the numbering
I have a masters thesis MS word file. I want to separate the chapters, each chapter in one Word file. I tried using copy and paste, but the problem is when I paste the chapter in a new file the numbering of the chapter changes and some numbers becomes letters. It confused me, is there any way to follow to avoid this?

You might want to ask a search engine of your choice about Word parent and child documents. A parent document can include a number of child documents with consistent numbering.
The following describes the manual process to adjust the numbering:
If you right-click in your heading, something similar to this should pop-up:

Left-click on the down-arrow right of the 1, 2, 3 list.
This shows a selection of numbering schemes:

At the bottom (sorry for the German ...), you find an option to change the starting value. This allows to start with a chapter number different from 1.
You'll have to update the start value whenever prior chapters are added.
To change the starting number for image captions, you can follow this video.
It explains how the change the text field which achieves the image counting. A start value parameter is added.
